# How to extract Table contents from an HTML page using BeautifulSoup in Python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the following [URL](https://repo.vse.gmu.edu/ait/AIT580/580books.html) and so far have been able to use the following code to extract out the `ul` elements.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import csv
import requests
page_link = 'https://repo.vse.gmu.edu/ait/AIT580/580books.html'
page_response = requests.get(page_link, timeout=5)
page_content = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, "html.parser")
print(page_content.prettify())
page_content.ul
```

However, my goal is to extract the information contained within the table into a csv file. How can I go about doing this judging from my current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I think that KunduKs answer provides an elegant solution using `pandas`, I would like to give you another approach, since you explicitly asked how to go on from your current code (which is using the `csv` module and BeautifulSoup).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import requests

new_file = '/path/to/new/file.csv'
page_link = 'https://repo.vse.gmu.edu/ait/AIT580/580books.html'
page_response = requests.get(page_link, timeout=5)
page_content = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, "html.parser")
table = page_content.find('table')

for i,tr in enumerate(table.findAll('tr')):
    row = []
    for td in tr.findAll('td'):
        row.append(td.text)
    if i == 0: # write header
        with open(new_file, 'w') as f:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(f, row)
            writer.writeheader() # header
    else:
        with open(new_file, 'a') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(row)
```

As you can see, we first fetch the whole table and then iterate over the `tr` elements first and then the `td` elements. In the first round of the iteration (`tr`), we use the information as a header for our csv file. Subsequently, we write all information as rows to the csv file.

Comment: This answer is awesome and exactly what I was looking for! My only issue now is that when the csv file is exported there are additional blank rows added between rows in the table. Any idea how I can remedy that situation?

Comment: Nevermind mind I was able to fix the above issue by adding newline='' to the open csv file statement:

Comment: My only issue now is wanting to also export the column headers into the csv file as those are still missing.

Comment: I just tested the snippet and it works fine - including the header. Did you mind the indentation?

Answer (score 3):

You can use python pandas library to import data into csv. Which is the easiest way to do that.

```
import pandas as pd
tables=pd.read_html("https://repo.vse.gmu.edu/ait/AIT580/580books.html")
tables[0].to_csv("output.csv",index=False)
```

To install pandas just use

```
pip install pandas
```

Comment: This answer was extremely helpful as it exported the html table into a csv file but I was looking to perform this action using beautifulsoup;

Answer (score 1):

Slightly cleaner approach using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page_link = 'https://repo.vse.gmu.edu/ait/AIT580/580books.html'

page_response = requests.get(page_link)
page_content = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, "html.parser")

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for items in page_content.find('table').find_all('tr'):
        data = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in items.find_all(['th','td'])]
        print(data)
        writer.writerow(data)
```